# How can I compare two separate list on google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I compare two separate list on google spreadsheets?.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TodGW.png)It is to know the availability of a product from one list if also is in the second list.

I tried to formulate a solution however I could not find the solution.

Comment: VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH

Comment: With the image given how would you make an example of this functions?

Comment: Presuming first list starts at A1 and second list starts at A13, then formula in B13: =VLOOKUP(A13,$A$1:$B$4,2,0)

Comment: Also there are examples https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en